# Set of numbers that add up 1 to n

Tags: combinatorics, problem-solving

I am currently trying to solve the following problem:

Given a number $n \in \mathbb{N}$, find the size of a set $S$ of positive numbers $s_1, \ldots, s_k\in \mathbb{N}$, such that

1. $\sum_{i=1}^kS_i = n$
2. $\forall l$: $1 \leq l \leq n : l$ is the sum of a subset of $S$.
3. $S$ is minimal (but may contain the same number more than once)

What is the minimal size for $S$?

I thought that adding 1, 2, 3, $\ldots$, $k$ to the set until the sum is equal to the desired $n$ was the (simple) solution, but apparently this is not always the minimal solution to the problem.
Is there a generic way of solving this problem or this type of problem?

Comment: Find $k$ such that $2^k\leq n< 2^{k+1}$. pick those $k+1$ powers of two less than $n$. Maybe you can do better?

Comment: @snulty Neat! You might consider turning this into a regular answer so i can accept it.

Comment: I actually don't think I'm correct now that I'm rereading this

Comment: It works, considering that i just need the _number of items_. Adding the highest power $2^k$ would actually exceed $n$, but i still need to add a certain number to the set twice.
Consider $n$ = 17: $2^3+2^2+2^1+2^0 = 8 + 4 + 2 + 1 = 15$.
Adding $2^4 = 16$ to the set would exceed $n$, but it is still correct in terms of the necessary number of items $k = 5$ .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @snulty for pointing me in the right direction here.

The problem can be solved by converting $n$ into powers of two. Take the highest power $2^k \leq n$.

Adding the next higher power $2^{k+1}$ (or, if $n = 2^k$, $2^k$ itself) would of course mean that $\sum_{i=1}^{k+1} S_i > n$, but instead imagine adding just the difference between $n$ and $\sum_{i=1}^{k} S_i$, since elements may be added more than once.

$S$ must therefore contain $k+1$ elements, since $2^0 = 1$ is the first element added to the set.

Comment: I agree this choice works well. Good job! How do we know it's the smallest size set though?

Comment: There is no possible smaller set that also fulfills requirement 2. Omitting any of the numbers in the set, or e.g trying to choose numbers to the power of three instead of two, would lead to a number $l$, $1 \leq l \leq n$, that could not possibly be expressed as a sum of elements of $S$.

Comment: Yeh but there's two senses of minimal. One is the minimal cardinality of all possible sets that fill the criterion, the other is that if one element is removed it no longer fulfills the criterion. The first is what you're asking and which I'm unsure of.

Comment: I think for a "real", mathematical proof, you'd have to use induction over all even and odd numbers to prove that a) using this method, all the criteria are fulfilled and b) omitting any of the numbers, or using different numbers, would mean that not all the criteria can be fulfilled.

The crucial point is that you need the powers of two in order to cover every even and odd number, and omitting any would lead to "holes" in the series.
For what it's worth: I handed in my answer and it got accepted, so the assumption seemed to be correct. I am aware, of course, that this is no proof.